# Start Synergy in Crunchbang at Login Screen

Tags: linux, synergy

I'm using Crunchbang Linux with Openbox and I would like to have Synergy  (http://synergy-foss.org/) autostart at the login screen.

I tried following: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Synergy however I'm a bit new to Linux and I'm not quite sure how I should go about doing that.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I want it to be the client.

I can get it to work after I manually login with the keyboard and mouse that are connected to it and then adding Synergy to the autostart.sh

What I want is Synergy to start before logging in, so I don't have to have a keyboard and mouse connected to the computer to login to it

Comment: where exactly do you get stuck? Do you want this system to be the client or the server?

Comment: ah sorry I want it to be the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openbox uses a file at ~/.config/openbox/autostart.sh to start files. You can add or remove things from this file.

In #!, you'll probably want to comment out the line that has cb-fortune in it, to remove the annoying "Statler Says" messages.

Since you're using #!, there's an easy way to get to this config. Hit <kbd>SUPER</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, and go to SETTINGS > OPENBOX CONFIG > EDIT AUTOSTART.SH

At the bottom, add a line that says `synergyc server-host-name &`, replacing server-host-name with... well... the server host name, save it, and restart with SETTINGS > OPENBOX CONFIG > RESTART

Comment: I got that to work however, I still have to login with the keyboard and mouse connected to the Crunchbang computer instead of the one from my Windows 7 Synergy server computer.

Comment: I've never used synergy, I can't be more help past setting things up to autostart. I'll look into it, though, it's something I've wanted to install.

Comment: Have you read through `man synergyc` and set up a config file?

Comment: Oh, I get your problem, since you aren't logged in, it isn't started. You'll want to have it run when the system boots, not when you log in. Hold on a minute, let me try a few things.

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to /etc/rc.local

`sudo nano /etc/rc.local`

I made it look something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits. 
#
# By default this script does nothing.

## Synergy Test thingy
echo "Starting Synergy Client"
synergyc lolhosttest

exit 0
```

If you switch to TTY1 (ctrl + alt + f1) you'll see it say "Starting Synergy Client" as the very last thing before prompting a log-in. If you do log in through the tty, and do top or htop, you'll see it's running. Since openbox wasn't started, obviously autostart.sh has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Sadly this did not work I have also tried: (sleep 10; DISPLAY=:0 synergyc 192.168.5.55)&    and that does not work as well, it simply isn't starting at the login screen, I'm thinking it may have something to do with SLiM (http://slim.berlios.de/)

Comment: Putting it in rc.local should start it as the kernel loads. :/ Join the IRC channel and ask in there, or check out the #! forums. Just load up xchat and it'll put you in the #! irc, and the forums are at crunchbanglinux.org still.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to do this is to `vi /etc/slim.conf`, set the default user and enable auto login:

```
default_user    yomomma
```

...

```
auto_login    yes
```

Then `vi .config/openbox/autostart` and add your synergy command.  (Protip: for recent versions of synergy, you can just add `synergy &` to the autostart file, and it will open the GUI, connect, and (if you check the Edit > Settings > Hide on Startup box) iconize on success!)

This isn't the best, and you should be able to write a script that is started by rc.local and waits until there is an X server/WM/whatever to connect to (maybe just something like `while ! synergyc --no-restart --enable-crypto theserverip; do sleep 1; done`?), but this works in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a full solution, so made this, parted from synergy home.
Ubuntu 19.10 with Lubuntu desktop.
As a result synergy client starts automatically after reboot and works on login screen.

1.

```
[Unit]
Description=Synergy Service
Requires=display-manager.service
After=display-manager.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c "sleep 10; /bin/systemctl set-environment SDDMXAUTH=$(/usr/bin/find /var/run/lightdm/ -type f)"
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "XAUTHORITY=${SDDMXAUTH} /usr/bin/synergyc -f --restart --name YOURCLIENTNAME --enable-crypto SRVPCNAME:24800"

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

You need to change your display manager in /var/run/...

2. `systemctl daemon-reload`
   `systemctl enable synergy`
3. Also, I had an issue with fingerprint, so I copied from my user /home/user/.synergy/SSL/Fingerprints/TrustedServers.txt to root's user home.